# Trying to organize scrapped BeautifulSoup table into a dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe

Okay, I've been beating my head against the wall enough on this one - I'm stuck! I'm trying to build a function that I can input the Favorite from Sagarin's College Football site and it will calculate the spread including the Home advantage.

I am trying to pull the "Predictions_with_Totals" from Sagarin's site:
http://sagarin.com/sports/cfsend.htm#Predictions_with_Totals

I can get to it with the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd
html = requests.get("http://sagarin.com/sports/cfsend.htm#Predictions_with_Totals").text
soup = bs(html, "html.parser")
#find and create the table we want to import
collegeFB_HOME_ALL = soup.find_all("pre")
collegeFB_HOME = collegeFB_HOME_ALL[6]
df_collegeFB = collegeFB_HOME
```

This gets me a very nice table with a few headers I would need to get past to get to the "meat" of the data.

```
Predictions_with_Totals
                                      These are the "regular method".                                _
HOME or CLOSEBY (c) team in CAPS                                                                     _
both teams in lower case                                                                             _
means "n" for NEUTRAL location                                                 Rating Favorite       _
                                                                               MONEY=odds to 100     _
    FAVORITE              Rating  Predict Golden  Recent   UNDERDOG             ODDS  PCT%    TOTAL  _
======================================================================================================
    CENTRAL FLORIDA(UCF)    6.35    4.66    5.99    7.92   smu                   200   67%    52.40
    ALABAMA                20.86   19.07   17.01   26.30   texas a&m             796   89%    42.65
```

snipped.....

However, I can't get rid of the top HTML code to format this into something useful.  If he had made this a table or even a list I think I would find it a lot easier.

I have tried to make a dictionary and use row.find based on searches here but I don't know why it isn't working for me - maybe I need to trash the first few rows before the "FAVORITES" row?  How would I do that?

```
output = []
for row in df_collegeFB:
    test = {}
    test["headers"] = row.find("FAVORITES")
    test['data'] = row.find('all')
    output.append(test)
```

Just gives me garbage.  I'm sure I'm putting garbage in so not surprised I'm getting garbage out.

```
print(output)
[{'headers': -1, 'data': -1}, {'headers': None, 'data': None}, {'headers': -1, 'data': 1699}, {'headers': None, 'data': None}, {'headers': -1, 'data': -1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you are after. But if you are trying to get that table, you can use regex. Probably not the most efficient way I did it here, but none the less, gets that table into a dataframe:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd
import re

html = requests.get("http://sagarin.com/sports/cfsend.htm#Predictions_with_Totals").text
soup = bs(html, "html.parser")
#find and create the table we want to import
collegeFB_HOME_ALL = str(soup.find_all("pre")[6])

pattern = re.compile(r"\s{1,}([a-zA-Z\(\)].*)\s{1,}([0-9\.\-]+)\s{1,}([0-9\.\-]+)\s{1,}([0-9\.\-]+)\s{1,}([0-9\.\-]+)\s{1,}(\D+)([0-9]+)\s{1,}([0-9%]+)\s{1,}([0-9\.]+)")

rows = []
# find all matches to groups
for match in pattern.finditer(collegeFB_HOME_ALL):
    row = {}
    for i, col in enumerate(['FAVORITE', 'Rating', 'Predict', 'Golden', 'Recent', 'UNDERDOG', 'ODDS', 'PCT%', 'TOTAL'], start=1):
        row[col] = match.group(i).strip()
        
    rows.append(row)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
                 FAVORITE Rating Predict  ... ODDS PCT%  TOTAL
0    CENTRAL FLORIDA(UCF)   6.35    4.66  ...  200  67%  52.40
1                 ALABAMA  20.86   19.07  ...  796  89%  42.65
2                  oregon  12.28   11.89  ...  362  78%  75.82
3              washington   8.28    8.47  ...  244  71%  64.72
4           james madison   8.08    8.52  ...  239  70%  64.71
..                    ...    ...     ...  ...  ...  ...    ...
104  east tennessee state   7.92    7.75  ...  235  70%  41.16
105           WEBER STATE  15.32   17.25  ...  482  83%  62.36
106              delaware   2.10    2.89  ...  126  56%  38.73
107                  YALE   0.87    0.83  ...  110  52%  54.32
108      YOUNGSTOWN STATE   2.11    4.51  ...  127  56%  48.10

[109 rows x 9 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks @chitown88.  This is exactly what I was looking for!  I am still new to the pandas data frames, and have not played with regex very much.  I appreciate the help!  I would vote up your answer but still too new to have the reputation to do that :)